# Порядок в предложении с несколькими сказуемыми

Tags: синтаксис

Во время прочтения фразы "парами ртути отравились и умерли 60 мастеров" в [статье на Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80#.D0.A1.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.BE_.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B0), мне показалось, что построена она неверно, и если дополнение стоит в начале предложения, то все последующие сказуемые должны относиться к нему. Соответственно, вторая часть предложения читается как "парами ртути... умерли", что лишено какого-либо смысла. Фразой, не вызывающей диссонанса, в данном случае является "отравились парами ртути и умерли 60 мастеров".

Есть ли какое-то правило, подтверждающее это чувство?

Comment: Лично у меня при первом прочтении фраза не вызвала никакого диссонанса. Пригляделся - да, ваша лучше. Но сомневаюсь насчет правила.

Comment: Думаю правильно было бы "отравилось и умерло 60 мастеров".

Comment: @Artemix потерялась информация, которая в данном случае важна.

Comment: "Парами ртути отравилось и умерло 60 мастеров" - ничего не потерялось.

Comment: @Artemix ладно, не суть, вопрос в том, есть ли ошибка в изначальном.

Comment: Портик обращен к окну Сената.
Здесь на золото идет игра.
И парами ртути умирают
нефартовые сегодня мастера.

Comment: Фраза диссонанса не вызывает у меня

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память `отравилось и умерло` будет одним составным сказуемым, а не несколькими

Comment: @Sugar составное глагольное сказуемое состоит из вспомогательного глагола и инфинитива: http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/703-14_sostavnye_skazuemye_sostavnoe_glagolnoe_skazuemoe.html

Comment: P.S. Пример с "грамоты":
_Я часто получаю и отправляю письма._
Комментарий источника: **два сказуемых поясняются одним общим дополнением**. http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_190

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вряд ли найдётся универсальное правило, но можно определить, почему первый вариант неудачен. Дело не столько в порядке слов (напр. возможны варианты с разным положением подлежащего), сколько в **тесном объединении** союзом "и" соседствующих **глаголов**. В результате взаимной связи они оказались в равной степени отнесёнными к вынесенному в начало предложения дополнению "парами ртути", *с падежом* которого может сочетаться лишь один из этих глаголов. *Разорвать связь* второго глагола с имеющимся дополнением можно разными способами. В предложенном вами (правильном) варианте союз "и" объединяет законченную конструкцию из глагола с индивидуально связанным дополнением и второй глагол без дополнения. Без нарушения смысла здесь можно напр. перенести "60 мастеров" из конца в начало.

> Отравились парами ртути и умерли 60 мастеров.
>
> 60 мастеров отравились парами ртути и умерли.

Другой вариант исправления (с сохранением акцента на "парах ртути") возможен при связывании второго глагола с дополнением в подходящем падеже:

> Парами ртути отравились и от последствий отравления (ими) умерли 60
>   мастеров.

Answer (score 2):

> "парами ртути отравились и умерли 60 мастеров"

`Парами ртути (отравились и умерли) 60 мастеров.`
Именно так, как сгруппировано скобками, читается по-русски машинально.

В скобках стоят (глагол и его уточнение). Вариации уточнения: (отравились насмерть). Выбор данного глагола потребовал уточнение, когда автор пожелал передать точный смысл картины.

Можно продемонстрировать, в чём неопределенность у этого глагола, примером:
`Парами ртути отравились 60, а умерли 10 мастеров.`

Пример из английского: `A man was (shot to death) == Человек был (застрелен)`. Уточнение `насмерть` или `и умер`, *to death*, в русском языке не нужно. Есть один глагол, `застрелить`, передающий именно этот единственный смысл.